# What is a better approach to avoid overlapping instances

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement behavior for 2 and 3-tuples of the Integral type class. I would also like to define behavior for a single value, but my approach seems to cause type errors.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class MyClass a where
    prints :: a -> String

instance (Show n, Integral n) => MyClass (n, n) where
    prints = show

instance (Show n, Integral n) => MyClass (n, n, n) where
    prints = show
```

Works as expected. But when I add

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-} -- Adding this or else it wont compile

instance (Show n, Integral n) => MyClass n where
    prints = show
```

I get the following errors

```
*Main> prints 1
"1"
*Main> prints (1,1)

<interactive>:132:1: error:
    • Overlapping instances for MyClass (Integer, Integer)
        arising from a use of ‘prints’
      Matching instances:
        instance [safe] (Show n, Integral n) => MyClass n
          -- Defined at question.hs:12:10
        instance [safe] (Show n, Integral n) => MyClass (n, n)
          -- Defined at question.hs:6:10
    • In the expression: prints (1, 1)
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = prints (1, 1)
```

How can these be overlapping instances? When defined in this way, do the types need to be wrapped in a constructor? Is there a better way to achieve something like this?

Comment: I don’t have time right now to write a full detailed answer, but this is down to how GHC performs instance resolution, see e.g. the description in https://artyom.me/lens-over-tea-1#aa

Comment: Actually, never mind, I misread the question; this is indeed a straightforward case of overlapping instances as described in @MarkSeemann’s answer

Comment: I don't think that class makes any sense to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to use either [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) or [`OneTuple`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/OneTuple-0.2.2.1/docs/Data-Tuple-OneTuple.html), depending on whether you need the extra layer of laziness that tuples provide or not.

```
instance Show a => MyClass (Identity a) where
    prints = show

-- OR

instance Show a => MyClass (OneTuple a) where
    prints = show
```

By including an additional type constructor at the front, it is clear (to us, and the compiler, both) that `OneTuple a` and `(a, a)` cannot both match the same type. (Without the constructor, `a` and `(a, a)` can both match the same type -- e.g. `(Int, Int)` matches `a` with `a ~ (Int, Int)`, and matches `(a, a)` with `a ~ Int`.) Of course you can also use your own reimplementation of either of these types with names more meaningful for your use case; the important thing here is the introduction of a type constructor that is visibly different than `(,)`.

Additionally, I recommend that you avoid repeating type variables in your instance heads, because they will cause the instance to be chosen less often than most users expect at first. Keeping just your `(n, n)` instance, so that you can actually load and use the file, try `prints (3 :: Int, 4)` in ghci to see what I mean -- most beginners would expect that to choose the `(Int, Int)` instance, but it doesn't. This can be avoided either with the usual equality constraint trick, as in

```
instance (Show a, a ~ b) => MyClass (a, b) where prints = show
instance (Show a, a ~ b, b ~ c) => MyClass (a, b, c) where prints = show
```

or, more idiomatically, by defining new type constructors that only accept one parameter in the first place, as in:

```
data Vector2 a = Vector2 a a deriving Show
data Vector3 a = Vector3 a a a deriving Show

instance Show a => MyClass (Vector2 a) where prints = show
instance Show a => MyClass (Vector3 a) where prints = show
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message lists the overlapping instances:

```
  Matching instances:
    instance [safe] (Show n, Integral n) => MyClass n
      -- Defined at question.hs:12:10
    instance [safe] (Show n, Integral n) => MyClass (n, n)
      -- Defined at question.hs:6:10
```

This is probably not a problem in this particular example because both has the same implementation (`show`). The compiler, however, doesn't know this.

Imagine that you had two different instances. For example, for the sake of argument, you might have defined one of the instances as:

```
prints x = show x ++ "foo"
```

Now, when you go `prints (1,1)`, the compiler doesn't know which instance to pick. It can't just arbitrarily pick one, because the output might differ.

In the OP case, I think that the simplest solution would be to remove the specific instances (i.e. `MyClass (n, n)` and `MyClass (n, n, n)`), since the more general instance also covers those specific cases, and has the same behaviour.

Comment: I have gotten myself into an xy-problem situation. My goal is to define different behavior for different n-tuples and was thinking I could utilize pattern matching to extract the values of the tuples. For example, different tuple sizes would return different constructors of a `data Vector n = Val n | Vector2 n n | Vector3 n n n` data type.

Comment: @Iain Fair enough. Have you tried using a `newtype` for some of the definitions?

Comment: I have not tried using newtype, wouldn't that be the same as defining a wrapper data type with different constructors?

Comment: @Iain Yes, except that there's no run-time cost associated with the wrapping.