# Generalized conversion of different types to different instance constructors

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define type class instances to work with vectors of 1-4 components of `Num`, represented as tuples. This has been the best solution I have found (from [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611778/what-is-a-better-approach-to-avoid-overlapping-instances))

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data OneTuple a = OneTuple a deriving Show

class MyClass a where
    prints :: a -> String

instance (Show n, Num n) => MyClass (n, n) where
    prints = show

instance (Show n, Num n) => MyClass (n, n, n) where
    prints (a, b, c) = foldl (++) "" $ map (++" ") $ map show [a,b,c]

instance (Show n, Num n) => MyClass (OneTuple n) where
    prints (OneTuple a) = show a
```

but this comes with the requirement that `prints 1` be written as `prints $ OneTuple 1` which is undesirable. I tried implementing a `tuplify` function for this, but

```hs
wrap :: (MyClass a) => (String -> String) -> a -> String
wrap f = f . prints

tuplify :: (MyClass b) => a -> b
tuplify (a,b) = (a,b)
tuplify (a,b,c) = (a,b,c)
tuplify a = OneTuple a

stringFunction :: String -> String
stringFunction = id

vectorToString x = wrap stringFunction $ tuplify x
```

doesn't compile. I am trying to arrive at something that looks like this

```hs
vectorToString (1,2,3)
vectorToString (1,2)
vectorToString 1
```

Is this even possible? I think I remember reading something about how a function's behavior should not change depending on the input type, which is exactly what `tuplify` is doing. Is there a different way I could solve this problem?
This is the error message from ghci:

```
question.hs:18:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘(a0, b0)’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          tuplify :: forall b a. MyClass b => a -> b
        at question.hs:17:1-32
    • In the pattern: (a, b)
      In an equation for ‘tuplify’: tuplify (a, b) = (a, b)
    • Relevant bindings include
        tuplify :: a -> b (bound at question.hs:18:1)
   |
18 | tuplify (a,b) = (a,b)
   |         ^^^^^

question.hs:18:17: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘(a0, b0)’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          tuplify :: forall b a. MyClass b => a -> b
        at question.hs:17:1-32
    • In the expression: (a, b)
      In an equation for ‘tuplify’: tuplify (a, b) = (a, b)
    • Relevant bindings include
        b :: b0 (bound at question.hs:18:12)
        a :: a0 (bound at question.hs:18:10)
        tuplify :: a -> b (bound at question.hs:18:1)
   |
18 | tuplify (a,b) = (a,b)
   |                 ^^^^^
```

Comment: You should make a typeclass for tuplify (with two parameters), since input and output types here differ in all your clauses.

Comment: `foldl (++)` is "accidentally quadratic" (should pretty much always be `foldr (++)`; obviously the time is not an issue here but it's not a good habit to just throw `foldl`s around willy-nilly because `foldl` is almost always wrong) and also [`intercalate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate) does the job better (no trailing space). Also, not able to write an answer right now, but something something overlapping instances; check the GHC manual and/or other questions on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I remember reading something about how a function's behavior should not change depending on the input type

Sounds like you're thinking of [the Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). But that's something from the OO world, which doesn't apply to Haskell. You can't even really *formulate* it, because Haskell has no subtypes.

Haskell does have a related principle though: parametrically polymorphic functions *can't* have different behaviour depending on which types are used. But this is not so much a principle the programmer should obey, as something that's *enforced by the language*. That's one reason why your different cases for `tuplify` can't possibly compile: there you try to, like, *pattern-match on types*. This is not something you can do in Haskell function declarations.

However, it is almost exactly what *typeclasses* do, and indeed your own typeclass does it already.

There's another problem with your `tuplify`: the signature `MyClass b => a -> b` means *the caller* gets to pick what both `a` and `b` are, and then the function would somehow have to be able to convert between them. For example it would have to be able to convert a 2-tuple into a 3-tuple. What you probably intend to express there is that every input type is associated a result type – i.e. a type-level function. We call those *type families*, and indeed you can write

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family Tuplified t where
  Tuplified (a,b) = (a,b)
  Tuplified (a,b,c) = (a,b,c)
  Tuplified t = t
```

However, that still doesn't really bring you any further: now you have a type-level function, but no corresponding value-level functions for the individual cases. That function would have to have type

```
tuplify :: t -> Tuplified t
```

but you can't define it without resorting to a type class. You *could* write such a type class, but then you would just run into the same problem you tried to solve in your other question in the first place!

I don't see how *any* of this makes sense. Probably, your class instances should actually be more like the standard `Show` class:

```
instance MyClass Integer where prints = show
instance MyClass Int where prints = show

instance (MyClass a, b~a) => MyClass (a,b) where
  prints (x,y) = '(' : prints x ++ "," ++ prints y ++ ")"
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. I wasn't defining the base instances, and was trying to generalize `Int` and `Integer` to any `Num`.